# unknown filesystem type ‘lvm2_member’

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, lvm, manjaro, luks

I have been trying to install Manjaro in a VirtualBox several times now and every time there is some failure. This latest install attempt with Manjaro-Architect seemed to complete despite a small hiccup when trying to add a key-file to the LUKS-encrypted system. But in the end, everything seemed to complete. However, when trying to boot I am dropped into an emergency shell.
The system I'm trying to create is UEFI with LVM over LUKS. I also made a separate encrypted `/boot` partition. The LVM partition has 3 logical volumes: for `/`, for `/home` and a swap partition.

So, when trying to boot, the first thing I encounter is a prompt asking me for a passphrase. When I type it in, after a while GRUB says something like "Slot 0 opened". But after a few seconds I get "no such device" error followed a UUID for the LVM logical volume where the root of the filesystem is supposed to reside (see attached screenshot):
[image]

After a few seconds Grub menu opens and I can choose "Manjaro" or "Advanced". But whatever option I choose the system doesn't boot. I get the following message after a few seconds:

```
mount: /new_root: unknown filesystem type 'lvm2_member'.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
```

followed by a `rootfs` prompt, where I can't do much. Doing a listing I see that the system is completely messed up, `fstab` has 0 size, and a folder named `/new_root` is present but empty. Obviously, the installation did not complete and something is wrong, but I can't figure out what. And I don't know what to do next! A search on Google didn't yield much useful information. Some help would be greatly appreciated. I first asked this question on a Manjaro forum, but after several days there were no answers, so I'm posting it here in the hope that someone knows what to do.

Comment: By default VIrtualBox use BIOS. Did you set explicitly to have UEFI for this virtual machine? And why do not try with BIOS installation?

Comment: Yes, I set it up explicitly to have EFI, because the plan is to install it on an UEFI system afterwards. Right now I'm trying to install in VirtualBox so that I won't end up with a non-working system. When I get the process and everything works as expected I plan to install it as the main OS.